# Backbone.js and underscore.js re-loading template

Tags: backbone.js, refresh, underscore.js-templating

I have an HTML document with an underscore template as such:

```
                <div id="listings">
                <script type="text/template" id="listing-collection-template">
                    <@ _.each(listingCollection, function(listing) { @>
                       <div class="row-fluid well well-small">
                            <img src="<@= listing.imageUri @>" width="200" height="150" class="img-rounded pull-left hidden-phone" style="padding-right:10px">
                            <h3 class="text-center text-info"><@= listing.propertyName @></h3>
                            <img src="" width="100" height="75" class="img-rounded pull-left hidden-tablet hidden-desktop" style="padding-right:10px">
                            <br />
                            <strong><@= listings.sleeps @> Sleeps</strong>
                            <div class="pull-right text-info"><strong>$<@= listing.priceRanges[0].from @></strong></div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="rating rating-5 pull-right"></div>
                        </div> 
                    <@ }); @>
                </script>
                </div>
```

Using backbone, I'm passing a collection to the template through a view. Here's my view code:

```
define(['backbone', 'listingView'], function (Backbone, ListingView) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#listings'),
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
                var listingTemplate = _.template($('#listing-collection-template').html(), { listingCollection: this.collection.toJSON() });
                $(self.el).empty();
                $(this.el).html(listingTemplate);
        }
    });
});
```

This is working just fine the first time I display the collection onto the page. However if I try to display it again, this line of code

```
var listingTemplate = _.template($('#listing-collection-template').html(), { listingCollection: this.collection.toJSON() });
```

can't find the template, because the template in the HTML has been overwritten by the collection I rendered the first time. How do I avoid this problem, or implement a "refresh" feature?

This is the code I'm calling to render the collection:

```
var listing = new Listing();
var listingCollection = new ListingCollection();
listingCollection.fetch({ reset: true }); // reset: true needed in order to trigger reset event on collection
listingCollectionView = new ListingCollectionView({ collection: listingCollection });
```

Comment: Rather than having your template inline where it will be used, just put it as part of the `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! All tutorials I saw online had it inline, I thought there was some purpose to that.

Comment: It's ok to have it inline if you don't also clear out the contents each time, but given that it's a template and not actual content, I think it makes more sense to move it elsewhere.

Comment: Note that `_.template(x)` returns a compiled version of the template as a function. So you could cache the template function on first use and keep the template `<script>` where it is. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CdGBu/ I'd still recommend that you keep your templates in `<head>` though.